# Add a background image using Styles : Xamarin Forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to add a background image to my Xamarin Forms App. I've tried the solution defined here : [Xamarin forms background image for all Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29950925/xamarin-forms-background-image-for-all-pages). But this doesn't seem to work.
 I've also tried setting it via Xaml like this

```
<Style TargetType="ContentPage">
    <Setter Property="BackgroundImage" Value="MyImage.jpg" />
</Style>
```

To no avail. Any pointers would be appreciated. I'm working on Xamarin Forms version 2.3.2.127

Comment: What's the result of setting a style to have background image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are defining an implicit `Style` for `ContentPage`, and if it's defined at the `Application` level `ResourceDictionary` it will be applied to all `ContentPage`s.

With the scarce context and information you are giving, I can only guess what's going on. You probably have no `ContentPage`s in your app, but multiple pages *inheriting* from `ContentPage`. If you want that to work, you have to set the property `ApplyToDerivedTypes` to `true` in your `Style`:

```xml
<Style TargetType="ContentPage" ApplyToDerivedTypes="true">
    <Setter Property="BackgroundImage" Value="MyImage.jpg" />
</Style>
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you.